# How to show segmented image?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I have a matrix of thresholds to segment my image. this is multithreshold segmentation and all of thresholds are ready.
now , how can I show my segmented image ?
between every period, I want it to have same gray level.
this code is wrong but will say what I need.

```
level = sort(thresholds);
I1 = I(0<I && I<level(1));
I1 = gray1;

I2 = (level(1)<I && I<level(2));
I2 = gray2;
```

this is my imagination but I can't change it to matlab code.
for example the number of thresholds elements are 5

Comment: change the && sign into &

Comment: @Ibezito that's ok but how about value of gray? what is suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
% read Matlab reference image 
I=imread('coins.png');

% thresholds
gray1=100; % lower limit
gray2=200; % upper limit
I(find(I<gray1))=0; % replace anything less than gray1 with zeros
I(find(I>gray2))=0; % replace anything more than gray1 with zeros
imshow(I);
```